# PHP 7.2 - FPM - NGINX - Can't get a php error log outputted no matter what I do

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

One of my endpoints returns 500 - Server error. I can't configure the system to show me where the crash is.

I've done this:

in `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`

```
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on;
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/www/html/production/php-error.log;
```

Comment: Try looking in `/var/log/nginx`, there should be some logs there.

Comment: yep. that was it. thanks. respond as answer so i can credit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx logs are usually found in `/var/log/nginx/`. If you want to modify the filename/directory, you will need to modify the `error_log` directive in the site configuration file, in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available` (same file, the sites-enabled files are linked to the same file in the /etc/nginx/sites-available folder)